# Zend Framework & memory_get_peak_usage

Tags: php, zend-framework, memory-management

How many kbytes use your site on Zend Framework? and what size is normal...?

```
// using
memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024;
```

Comment: Since this is highly dependent on what the application does and how it is coded, it doesnt make sense to collect other people's numbers, as there will be no meaningful normal average. If you feel your memory usage is too high, use a profiler to identify any memory leaks. Also adding true as the parameter will collect the system's peak memory, not the executing script's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it will depend a lot on the running script and what operation is currently performed, just for info mine on local machine is 2816kb, no other operations, just simple output :)